# Duration of Schengen visa (French) that will be issued if I ask for Multiple entry?

Tags: schengen-visas

I am applying for a French Schengen visa (tourist purposes). I have given a duration of travel when I filled my personal information on French embassy website. Now I always presumed that the travel dates are temporary since you're not advised to book a plane ticket but "block" it. Also I wasn't sure of exact dates so I chose "multiple entry" option. Thus so far I have presumed I will receive a visa valid for 90-days with multiple entry.

I am planning a 9-day trip next month and another short trip the month after, although exact dates are flexible at this point. Now I read one some forum that a person was issued Schengen visa for exactly the duration that he had stated on the form.

My visa interview is this week and I wanted to make sure it's OK to let the visa officer know/to ask the VO that I need multiple entry visa with longer validity (ideally atleast 30 days). Is that OK?

Comment: For clarity, are both your intended trips to France?

Comment: Yes both trips and most days of the trip are (mostly) in France.

Answer (score 1):

First time or infrequent travellers to the Schengen region (particularly from countries where illegal immigration is a concern), are likely to get a single entry visa covering the duration of their stay (sometimes with a few days margin). 
You should make it clear in your covering letter that you intend to travel more than once and perhaps block tickets for your next journey too.

Comment: If I can prove that I will be doing two trips (by having the flight itinerary, hotel reservation and medical insurance), will that help my case?

Comment: Yes and the means to support yourself for the 2 trips.

Comment: @CHJ Have you already applied and submitted your documents? The decision will be based on the information you provided, I’m not sure that significant extra information will be accepted at the interview, if that’s what you’re hoping for. Others may be able to shed more light on this.

Comment: @Deans, I do have sufficient funds as I am working full-time in US. Traveller, while filling application you can only specify one entry and exit date, not multiple. So I can say I prudently and honestly added the first trip days only. I hope they don't ask me to apply multiple times for visa.  If they only give me visa for first travel is second visa possible without visa interview?